# Comparing char for validation in C++

Tags: c++, validation

```
 /*
 PROGRAM: Ch6_14.cpp
 Written by Corey Starbird
 This program calculates the balance
 owed to a hospital for a patient.
 Last modified: 10/28/13
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Prototypes for In-patient and Out-patient functions.
double stayTotal (int, double, double, double); // For In-patients
double stayTotal (double, double);              // For Out-patients

int main()
{

    char    patientType;        // In-patient (I or i) or Out-patient (O or o)
    double  rate,               // Daily rate for the In-patient stay
    servCharge,                 // Service charge for the stay
    medCharge,                  // Medication charge for the stay
    inTotal,                    // Total for the In-patient stay
    outTotal;                   // Total for the Out-patient stay
    int     days;               // Number of days for the In-patient stay

    // Find out if they were an In-patient or an Out-patient
    cout << "Welcome, please enter (I) for an In-patient or (O) for an Out-patient:" << endl;
    cin >> patientType;
    while (patientType != 'I' || 'i' || 'O' || 'o')
    {
        cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter either (I) for an In-patient or (O) for an Out-patient:" << endl;
        cin >> patientType;
    }



    cout << "FIN";

    return 0;
}
```

Hey, brand new to C++ here.  I am working on a project and I'm having trouble figuring out why my validation for `patientType`isn't working properly.  I first had double quotes, but realized that would denote strings. I changed them to single quotes, my program will compile and run now, but the while loop runs no matter what I enter, I, i, O, o, or anything else.

I don't know why the while loop isn't checking the condition, seeing that I did enter one of the characters in the condition, and move on to cout. Probably a simple mistake, but I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your while condition is wrong.

You most likely want this:

```
while (patientType != 'I' && patientType != 'i' && patientType != 'O' && patientType != 'o')
```

You got to use `&&`. `patientType` isn't `I` or it isn't `i` would be always true. Also you got to use `patientType !=` for every item being checked or the characters `i`, `o`, `O` would be implicitly converted to `bool` (`true` for all of them).

Comment: Any other suggestions I can explore to make this kind of validation cleaner? Rather than repeating the same thing for every option.  For example, if inputs can be one of 10 letters, upper or lower case, but nothing else?

Comment: @CoreyStarbird might use patientType = std::tolower(patientType) before the while to only have to check for lower case versions in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (patientType != 'I' && patientType != 'i' &&
       patientType != 'O' && patientType != 'o')
```

As written, the condition is always true, because three of the four expressions OR-ed together are non-zero.

Comment: I can suggest use `tolower` function here.

Comment: Any other suggestions I can explore to make this kind of validation cleaner? Rather than repeating the same thing for every option.  For example, if inputs can be one of 10 letters, upper or lower case, but nothing else?

Comment: `string options = "IiOo"; if (options.find(patientType) != string::npos) { /* correct choice */ }`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line

```
(patientType != 'I' || 'i' || 'O' || 'o')
```

This doesn't do what you think, you want

```
(patientType != 'I' && patientType != 'i' && patientType != 'O' && patientType != 'o')
```

The comparison operators are strictly between two values, the left and right side.

C and C++ treat any value that is not zero as being "true". So,

```
(patientType != 'I' || 'i' || 'O' || 'o')
```

Was being translated as

```
(patientType != 'I') or ('i' is not 0) or ('O' is not 0) or ('o' is not 0)
```

Comment: So, I am guessing that !|| does not mean nor? ;)

Comment: lol - it doesn't :) I just edited the translated as to try and make what I was describing a little clearer :)

Comment: Ooo the new translation makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Comment: Any other suggestions I can explore to make this kind of validation cleaner? Rather than repeating the same thing for every option.  For example, if inputs can be one of 10 letters, upper or lower case, but nothing else?

Comment: One way would be to declare a std::string with the list of characters, `const std::string options("IiOo")`. To test if the patientType is valid, `(options.find(patientType) != std::string::npos)`